# How to output all the elements in an array in the following output?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

After every 5 elements the next element should be printed on the next line. I am not allowed to use a string of empty spaces for the space between the elements. I tried using GoToXy, but I am having trouble. All elements in the first row have 5 spaces between them, starting from the second row all the elements need to be aligned to the one above it.

**Desired Output:**

```
94     2     67     57     7
40     58    48     73     94
16     77    88     16
```

**Output from my code:**
(Everything is printed on the same line with 5 spaces between them.)

```
94     2     67     57     7     40     58    48     73     94     16   77    88     16
```

My code is:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
count = 14
array WORD count DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

    push OFFSET array
    push COUNT
    call ArrayFill
    call DisplayArray

    exit

main ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrayFill PROC  
    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    pushad              ; save registers
    mov esi,[ebp+12]    ; offset of array
    mov ecx,[ebp+8]     ; array size
    cmp ecx,0           ; ECX == 0?
    je  L2              ; yes: skip over loop

L1:
    mov eax, 100            
    call    RandomRange ; from the link library
    mov [esi],ax
    add esi,TYPE WORD
    loop    L1

L2: popad               ; restore registers
    pop ebp
    ret 8               ; clean up the stack
ArrayFill ENDP

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DisplayArray PROC

mov eax, 0
mov esi, 0
mov ecx, COUNT
mov dh, 0
call GoToXy
mov dl, 5

L1:
    mov ax, array[esi * TYPE array]
    call WriteDec
    call GoToXy
    add dl, 5
    inc esi
    loop L1
    call CrlF
ret
DisplayArray ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: MASM in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You aren't allowed to use a string of empty spaces?  What about tabs (ascii 9) and newline (ascii 13 + ascii 10)?

Comment: @MattJordan I can't use empty spaces but I can use tabs, and newline. Could you point me towards how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab characters auto-align on most consoles, so printing a tab character (ascii 9) will align to an 8-character column format automatically.

A tab character should be printed before printing the next decimal value from the array when `dl` equals 1, 2, or 3 within your `L1` loop.  By not printing a tab when `dl` is 0, the first column will stay left-justified.

When `dl` is 4 in your `L1` loop (4 represents the fifth value for each row), output a newline (crlf) after printing and then reset `dl` to 0 for the next 5.  Resetting `dl` allows you to use simple comparisons, since you only have 5 possible values to check.

`GoToXy` seems to be interfering with your `CrlF`, although without the code for either of those I cannot tell in what way.  Using the approach I have outlined, you won't need `GoToXy` at all, but you will still need `CrlF`, so I suggest that you verify it actually works.